# filter through one excel spreadsheet using data from another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 excel files. One holds some products that i need to put into a database but it doesnt have all of the information i need.

The second file has all the information for these products but there are several thousand more products that i do not need.

What I need to do is filter through this larger file for the products from the smaller one. How do I go about doing this?

Here is a snippet of the smaller file with missing info.
[image: Here is a snippet of the smaller file]

Here is a snippet from the larger file that i need to filter through
[image: and here is a snippet from the larger file that I need to filter through]

The unique identifier (catalog number) is present in both files

Comment: Could you put both files into the database and then just do a `join` of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the VLOOKUP-function.
Check this page or the built-in help on the function:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

You can retrieve the missing info from your larger file into your smaller file joining them on the unique id. Pay attention to the last parameter of the function it can make or break your concept.

Comment: you were right I needed a V lookup. Had no idea how to do it but have managed it now thanks :)

Comment: good to hear you managed and learnt how to. usually the Excel Help is helpful if you're familiar with the basics. You're welcome!